# How to design a table if it has no candidate keys?

Tags: database, relational-database, normalization, database-normalization

Currently in my database class we are discussing the relational model and normalization and so on. I have answered every question in my homework with ease but this one has thrown me for a loop:

> - If a table has no candidate keys, then what is the general practice to design a table?

There is no example here of a table with no candidate keys. The question above is all I have and I feel like that's too vague.

My first thought was to find any determinants (even if they were not a candidate key) and create a new table with those functional dependencies, but I don't even know that any functional dependencies exist in the table in the first place. Is there a possible answer for this?

Comment: Why would someone vote to close this question?

Comment: Apparently, it is too broad.  There might well be another question that this is a duplicate of.  One serious question would be to reassess the contents of the table; why is there no candidate key?  What data is it holding?  Are you sure there is no way to distinguish the superficially identical rows — based, perhaps, on the time at which the data was recorded?

Comment: @JonathanLeffler I don't. That's why I'm confused. There's no specific example to look at, so maybe all of the things you just mentioned as well as Andrew's answer are what my professor is looking for. Not how to fix it, but steps that could be taken toward fixing it? I will have to ask him what he is looking for, but I thought this was a good question to bring here as part of a normalization discussion.

Comment: The fallback is to add an 'identity' column of some sort, but it is not ideal.  Examining the data and understanding what it means is crucial.  I think it was Codd who noted that 'saying something twice does not make it any truer'.  The rows in a table are assertions of truth; having two rows saying the same thing is a asserting the same thing twice.  There must be some difference between the rows — otherwise you would not insert both.  So what is it that distinguishes the two rows?

Comment: Well that's why I'm confused. Assuming our table is in *at least* the first normal form, I can't imagine it doesn't have a candidate key. But it is possible.

Comment: It can be that a table doesn't have a candidate key.  It's not quite a pathological case, but I've only seen it a couple of times in 25 years.  In both of those cases the data was transactional but not even the whole row taken together was guaranteed to be unique.  In both of the real-world cases I've actually seen, the data was not meant to be updateable, which is good since there was no way to tell which instance of duplicated row values to update if it had come up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create an additional column that is guaranteed to be unique (auto-increment integer) for example.

Comment: Wow. That was hell of a face palm I just had right there. That makes a lot of sense, but I suppose there's still some assumptions made. If I create an id for each row, I would have to assume each row represents some specific object or fact, wouldn't I?

Comment: Yes, here's the whole point of relational databases, each table is a relation.  Each row means the items on that row are related by whatever the table is to represent.  For example, a purchases table could have a customer id, a date, and an item id.  So if there's a row in the table that is "c2345", "1/1/2014", "12345", then it means customer c2345 bought item with id 12345 on 1/1/2014.

Comment: That makes sense, and that table doesn't have a candidate key does it? you can have multiple customers, same date, same items, so it would make sense to give each purchase its own id.

Comment: @McAdam331 The comment table "customer C bought item with id I on D" has a CK--all columns. Whether "you can have multiple customers, same date, same items" or not, that table doesn't happen to tell you about whether such events happened more than once. If you want a table that does then you have pick a different meaning. See my answer.

Answer (score 4):

A table, if it is to be relational, always has at least one candidate key (all attributes combined).  Tables that allow duplicate rows are not relational.  So if you were talking *relational*, the scenario simply doesn't occur.  There always is a candidate key.

Comment: Then what would be common practice to _make_ it relational? Or is there just not enough information, because I imagine the case is different each time. I think this is just a poorly worded question, or they meant for it to be wide open.

Comment: The practice to "make it relational" is, alas, not common.  Declare the key.

Comment: thanks again for the help. Can I recruit you for another database design [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26821417/is-a-candidate-key-determinant-good-enough-for-bcnf)?

Answer (score 1):

A relational table is a *set* of rows so *can't have* duplicate rows and always has one or more CKs. The table with meaning "customer C bought item I on D" has all columns as CK. The C-I-D triples that make a true statement from that go in the table. But "customer C bought item I on D for the Nth time" or "purchase P was customer C buying item I on D" give other tables.

Your quote is about *another kind of table* with *another kind of meaning*. Find out what those are! Instead of "This table (is relational so it) is the (set of) rows that make the following into a true statement: ..." you will be told something like "This table is a list of descriptions of purchases...". Nb how that uses relevant things or notions. Then pick a relational meaning/table referring to or using them.

PS CKs are *relational*. Non-relational tables *can't have* CKs. They can have minimal unique column sets *over a list of rows* but that's not a CK.