# Is a candidate key determinant good enough for BCNF?

Tags: mysql, database, relational-database, database-normalization, bcnf

A question that came up in my homework is as follows:

- If a determinant is part of a candidate key, is that good enough for BCNF?

I don't think so, because a relation is in BCNF if all non-key attributes depend on the whole primary key, and nothing else. This says the determinant is *part* of a candidate key, so does this imply a partial functional dependency?

However, I began to second guess myself because there's a possibility that the candidate key is a super key, but it doesn't seem like that is the case.

What do you think?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What does the question mean by "part"? Some but not all of? Some or all of? What do you mean by it?

The definition of partial functional dependency uses "partial" to mean some but not all of.

Check definitions of BCNF. The one that requires that no non-prime attribute be partially functionally dependent on any key also requires other things than you wrote. So your "if" is not correct. But if the assignment question's "part" means "part of but not all of" as in "partially dependent" then by the relevant definition of BCNF the relation is not in BCNF.

All candidate keys are superkeys. But the candidate keys are the superkeys that do not contain any smaller superkeys. Superkeys are involved in a different form of the definition of BCNF. But if BCNF is violated according to one definition and what you know, it can't possibly be allowed by another one.

Comment: Well, to answer your first question, that's part of my confusion. It has the tone to me that it means 'some but not all of'. So you would say, in that case, that it is not enough for BCNF?

Comment: Which is what I think, too, but I felt there was a bit of ambiguity and a good opportunity to bring that question here.

Comment: But the *ambigutity* of "part" in the assignment has nothing to do with BCNF. Either find out what it means or answer it for both meanings. They should be using proper terminology in the first place, although likely they think they are, with "part" supposed to be tied to "partial".

Comment: I will find out what our professor thinks tomorrow, as the assignment is due and we will be going over it, but I have a feeling there will be an interesting debate in class about what the textbook authors were going for.

Comment: However, I chose to say that this was not enough, because an attribute should depend on the whole key. I suspect that is what he is expecting, and often whenever there is a lot of ambiguity and disagreement in the class he tends to give the question to everyone, should that *not* be what he is looking for..

Comment: "That case" is answered in the question! Find the definition(s) of BCNF you were given.